# Recommendation for a CMS / web frontend for news articles (read only)

Tags: cms

I have a number of news articles, fairly simple with headline, a picture and some text. These are in HTML format and organized by date.

Each article is (preferred) stored as the **article** itself, example:

```
<div class="article">
...
</div>
```

For this reason, the CMS should ideally have some sort of template engine.

I would like to view the articles in a CMS, as alternative to opening files in a browser. The articles will be created by script, so NO manual editing needed.

It is not important if the CMS is storing data as files, MySQL or SQLite. I am flexible there, just adapting the script.

The CMS should ideally run in a WAMP server, but node.js is also possible.

Any idea of a read-only presentation frontend with templating support ?

Answer (score 0):

[Eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev/) sounds like it might be a good fit. It runs in node.js, offers several templating engines, and will generate a full, linked site that you can drop on a webserver for read-only browsing.